# Не срабатывает смена src в iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
function closeMusic() {
                    var music = window.parent.document.getElementById("music");
                    music.style.display = "none";
                    var content = window.top.document.getElementById("content");
                    content.src = "../../bands/rrr/rrr.php";
                    }



<form class="delButton" id="delAlbButton" method="post" action="../../../../scripts/php/deletealbum.php">
                        <input type="hidden" value="'.$BN.'" id="BNforDel" name="BN"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="'.$AN.'" id="ANforDel" name="AN"/>
                        <input type="submit" onClick="closeMusic();" value="DEL">
</form>
```

по нажатию вызывается скрипт удаления этой страницы

и js ф-я, которая вдругой iframe подгружает страницу

выдаёт Failed to load resource: the server responded with a http://localhost/bands/rrr/rrr.php status of 404 (Not Found)

путь точно верный указан

хотя тот что выдаёт и нужный различные

нужный http://localhost/NetFM/bands/rrr/rrr.php

помогите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `onClick="closeMusic();"` используй `onsubmit`.

```
var form = document.getElementById('delAlbButton');

form.onsubmit = function(){
  closeMusic();
}
```

использование *абсолютный путь* (absolute path) для URL.

```
content.src = "http://localhost/NetFM/bands/rrr/rrr.php";
```